# How to simulate fading channels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fading-channel

In [this page](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/commblks/usersguide/tutor3-3.html), an example simulating Rician and Rayleigh fading in parallel is given. I knew that Rician fading simulates both line of sight and none light of sight components, so why do we need to simulate it in parallel with Rayleigh fading?

Comment: Please fix your original question before asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

We generally consider Rician fading when there's one dominant path, typically a LOS path, and Rayleigh fading when there's no LOS path.

Of course, both fadings are named after the distribution that their amplitude gain follows – Rayleigh and Rice distributions. And you're right, Rayleigh is a special case of Rice for $\nu=0$, but you typically parameterize the scale of the Rayleigh distribution differently for the NLOS model – which makes sense, physically, because there's well, no line of sight.

Comment: Could you please give more explanation.

Comment: If the Rayleigh channel is simulated with four multipath components having delays [0 ,1.5, 2, 3] μs and average path gains of [0, -2,-3, 1] dB, and the Racian fading is simulated with k=1. What is the difference between simulating them in parallel, and simulating each one alone?